# how to handle jquery effects after pagination

Tags: jquery, data-view-web-part

I have a jquery effect that manger hover events on images in a Data View Webpart.  When the page loads the hovers work find in the table.  But when I click next to paginate to the next set the hovers stop.  What do I need to modify to have the effect continue to work after pagination?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("img.ILikeItImg").hover(function(){
     $(this).attr("src", '/SiteAssets/facebook_like_buton.png');
    }, function() {
     $(this).attr("src", '/SiteAssets/facebook_like_buton_small_gray.png');
   });
})
```

Comment: This is very similar to this question:  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39157/re-executing-jquery-function-on-list-manipulation/39168#39168

Comment: yes similar but slightly different.  I kluged a solution to the other question but this seems to be a very consistent issue which I am trying to get my arms around.  Thanks for reading though.

Comment: Which JS event did you find for the other solution?

Comment: It seems that SharePoint ajax refresh of the data causes my  entire jquery script to disappear!?  I can see this in firebug script window as all of my code goes bye-bye on pagination.  It is doing this on this page but not the other one referenced above.  Very odd.

Comment: Disabling ajax Asynchronous Update option on my list causes the page to reload and thus my jquery code to be reloaded.  That will be my solution for now until we understand more.